# Convert char para data - Hive

Tags: sql, cast, hadoop, hive

Preciso concatenar duas colunas que são char para transformar em data, mas com o código abaixo a parte do horário fica zerada.
As duas colunas possuem informações e não estão nulas ou em branco.

```
CAST(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(CONCAT(
substr(dt_atendimento_fcdr, 1, 4), '-', substr(dt_atendimento_fcdr, 5, 2), '-', substr(dt_atendimento_fcdr, 7, 2), ' ',
substr(hr_atendimento_fcdr, 1, 2), ':', substr(hr_atendimento_fcdr, 3, 2), ':', substr(hr_atendimento_fcdr, 5, 2)), 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss')) as timestamp)
```

O resultado é esse: [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Os dados nas colunas:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Obrigada!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
cast( 
    substr(dt_atendimento_fcdr, 1, 4) || '-' || substr(dt_atendimento_fcdr, 5, 2) || '-' || substr(dt_atendimento_fcdr, 7, 2) || ' ' ||
    substr(hr_atendimento_fcdr, 1, 2) || ':' || substr(hr_atendimento_fcdr, 3, 2) || ':' || substr(hr_atendimento_fcdr, 5, 2)
  as timestamp)
```